# How to purge the options table of wp session entries automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I'm looking for a way to automatically purge the database of `_wp_session` records in WordPress.

The SQL query I have is:

```
DELETE
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE option_name LIKE '_wp_session%'
```

I would like to know how I can run it once per day with a plugin, PHP script or cron job.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should schedule an event that occurs daily. You can do this for example in a custom plugin.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action('my_daily_event', 'do_this_daily');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_daily_event');
}

function do_this_daily() {
    $wpdb->query(
      "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options
       WHERE option_name LIKE '_wp_session%'
      "
    )
}
```